# Why would a CD Rate be higher than a Corporate Bond rate?

Tags: united-states, bonds, price, certificate-of-deposit, liquidity

In looking at my brokerage account for fixed income products, I was looking at both CDs and Corporate Bonds.  I was surprised to see that the best 1-year CDs had a higher interest rate than any AAA or AA bonds.  (A was slightly higher than the best 1-year CDs).

Why would somebody buy a corporate bond with a lower interest rate over a CD that is FDIC insured?

My money would be locked up in both, but I could sell both on the secondary market if I needed the money early.  I'm guessing it's easier to find buyers for a corporate bond on the secondary market, so I could probably get a better price.  Could that be a reason why these bond rates are slightly lower?

Comment: Consider that FDIC insurance has a $250,000 limit. For institutional investors and businesses (even small businesses), investments will easily exceed this limit. Therefore, the financial soundness of the bank will be a real factor.

Comment: Were the bonds priced at par (100)? I would guess that even a AAA bond issued at 2 or 3 percent would currently trade at a decent discount.

Answer (score 2):

The investor might choose the bond if it is more liquid (easier/cheaper/quicker to sell) or if the amount they wish to invest is more than the FDIC limit.